# Angular value is parsed when printed, but not as a directive attribute

Tags: javascript, data-binding, angularjs, directive

I have an array of addresses called `addressesForUser`. I also have an "address" directive with an isolate scope.

When I do this:

```
<div ng-repeat="add in addressesForUser" entryid="{{ add.id }}">{{ add.id }}</div>
```

all is well, and for three addresses I get the following generated html:

```
<div entryid="1">1</div>
<div entryid="2">2</div>
<div entryid="3">3</div>
```

but when I do this:

```
<address ng-repeat="add in addressesForUser" entryid="{{ add.id }}"></address>
```

and then try to `console.log(attrs.entryid)` within the directive's linking function, I get "add.id" as a string in the output. Worse yet, the attribute in the generated html is undefined - only the attribute name is there - so it's neither a number from 1 to 3, nor the string "add.id".

What am I doing wrong? The end goal is having each address directive read in its entryid attribute, so it can auto-populate independently and generate an address card, or if the entryid is missing, it shows a form to enter a new address. The latter part works fine, but I can't understand why it's not reading in the entryid value.

Edit: When I don't use isolate scope (i.e. I remove "scope: {}" from the directive), it works. But I need isolate scope, so I suppose I just need a way to make the attribute get included in the scope of the individual directive. Here's a slightly stripped down address directive code:

```
myapp.directive('address', ['GeoService', '$http', function (gs, http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'address.html',
        scope: {
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.emptyForm = {
                first_name: '',
                last_name: '',
                country: '',
                city: '',
                street: '',
                phone: '',
                is_def: '',
                zip: '',
                additional_info: '',
                residence_type: ''
            }

            console.log(attrs.entryid);

            scope.countries = gs.countries();
            scope.resetAddressForm = function(e) {
                scope.newAddressForm = scope.emptyForm;
            }
            scope.saveAddress = function() {
                http.post('/users/saveaddress', scope.newAddressForm).then(function (response) {

                   console.log(response.data); // Do something
                });
            }
            scope.$watch('newAddressForm.country', function(v) {
                if (v != undefined) {
                    scope.cities = gs.cities(v);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: I think you need to post your address directive code for better understanding of this issue, a [plunker](plnkr.co/edit/) example would be better, anyway I think it because of the isolation, there's something wrong there, I can't tell without seeing the directive's code.

Comment: Updated original post with directive code. It is isolate scope, it works if I remove isolation, but I need it in this case.

Comment: As you said in your answer the solution `scope: {entryid: '=' }`, but that's if you'r going to use it in the template, for the link function as [@Josh David Miller](http://stackoverflow.com/users/259038/josh-david-miller) said in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your directive does not modify the value of `add.id` (hence you don't need two-way databinding), I suggest using `@` rather than `=`.  Once defined with `@`, you can use `attrs.$observe()` or `scope.$watch()` to get the interpolated value:

```
scope: {
   entryid: '@',
},
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    attrs.$observe('entryid', function(value) {
        console.log('observed value=',value);
    });
    scope.$watch('entryid', function(value) {
       console.log('watched value=',value);
    });
    ...
}
```

<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/nYLCR/)</kbd>

Comment: Wish this was _anywhere_ in the docs. Egghead doesn't cover this too well either. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is actually that in directives you **cannot** assume that an attribute is ready when the `link` function runs. If the value is interpolated, it will often not be available to you. The canonical way of accessing an attribute is through `$observe`:

```js
link: function ( scope, element, attrs ) {
  attrs.$observe( 'entryid', function ( val ) {
    // do something with the val
  });
}
```

If you are using an isolate scope, it is probably a good idea to add scope properties for common attributes but you still shouldn't assume the value to be available during the `link`. You should always use the `$observe` method if the value could possibly need to be interpolated.

Comment: Interesting. When I try to reformat my directive to use observe like you said, though, it never interpolates the value. `console.log(val)` gives me add.id, the string, instead of the actual value, and {{ add.id }} also gets returned as a literal string. What gives?

Comment: You'll have to post a Plunker as this should universally work.

Answer (score 0):

After some more tinkering, I got the solution by accident. The documentation could really use some more work in this area.

Essentially, the isolate scope needs to be defined as such:

```
scope: {entryid: "="}
```

and the value is then accessed via scope, not via attrs, as in

```
console.log(scope.entryid);
```